# Manter um Fork no Git com duas ou mais fontes diferentes e excluindo diretórios

Tags: git

Estou trabalhando com o **QEMU** para fazer testes e integração continua de um projeto que usa o **OpenCV** e **TBB**, porém preciso manter um *Fork* do **QEMU** que usa apenas alguns recursos do original, somado com outros recursos adicionados por um segundo *Fork*.

Nem todos os diretórios são necessários para meu Fork, então gostaria de usar o **Git** de forma que ele fizesse apenas o checkout de alguns diretórios, sei que posso fazer isso dizendo quais diretórios quero no checkout limitando assim o que é baixado para meu Workspace.

porém vi que o **Git** tem um recurso mais especifico, chamado **Sparce Checkout**, porém não consige ainda compreender como usa-lo neste perspectiva.

Em resumo tenho um repositório xyz e outro zwk onde preciso obter de cada um respectivamente os grupos de diretório:

- A, B, F, R
- B, G, R

Finalmente teria uma nova estrutura de diretórios:

- A, B, F, G, R

Sendo os demais arquivos  que possam existir em cada repositório original ignorados.

Como podem ver há dois diretórios em comum, portanto terei que fazer um *merge* desdes dois diretórios e claro avento conflito terei que intervir manualmente e gerar um novo *commit* com os ajustes que for preciso. Caso contrário tudo corrento automática mente eu prosseguirei com o *commit* padrão e geração do pacote compilado.

Há como usar o **GIT** para esta tarefa de unir grupos de diretórios em um novo ***Fork*** (entenda *fork* como um repositório)